# Instance variables in the webservice

Tags: java, web-services

I am struck with a problem in webservice. I have a count variable declared as a member variable in a bean.  I am incrementing   the value of count each time webservice is called.The count variable is not set to zero for a new session. It goes on incrementing for the new session. can u please tel me how to set the value of count to zero.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
if (session.isNew()) {
    count = 0;
}
```